# limit notation $x \rightarrow 1^-$?

Tags: limits, notation

I am looking for a clarification of the following notation:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}f(x)$$

In particular, does the $1^-$ mean that $1$ is approached from below in the limit?

Comment: Yes, it does.${}$

Comment: That is exactly what it means.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it means exactly that $1$ is approached from below.  Formally, $L=\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $1-\delta<x<1$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.